# onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver does not get called

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am using *AlarmManager* to create an alarm by playing a sound. To do this, I first create a *PendingIntent*, for which I have to create a class called *AlarmReceiver*, which extends *BroadcastReceiver*. In this new class, I override the *onReceive* method, in which I also start the sound. However, from what I've tested, the onReceive method is not even called from the MainActivity.

After some research, I found out that I should declare the receiver in the manifest file. Thus, I declare it, but it doesn't recognize the name of the class, *AlarmReceiver*, it shows it in red. I don't fully understand how to properly declare in the manifest file. I know there are other similar SO questions and I've checked them all, but I am still not able to get it work.

The code for the MainActivity is:

```
package com.example.alarmsound;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music);
        Log.d("Music", "It went here.");
        mp.start();

        Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
    t.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

    Context context = this;
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, t.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
}
```

And the declaration in Manifest is:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.alarmsound.AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.alarmsound.MainActivity" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I could also be doing something wrong in the MainActivity, even though I think I'm doing everything right there.

Comment: You have your AlarmReceiver within your MainActivity class. So you can't declare com.example.alarmsound.AlarmReceiver as the android:name. You would have to declare MainActivity.AlarmReceiver

Comment: I just tried that, but it still doesn't work, @Steve. I think the main problem is that it doesn't recognize the name of the AlarmReceiver class, in the line above. It shows it in red and cannot resolve it.

Comment: Thats because it can't find the class you're specifying. Mainly because your AlarmReceiver is not a standalone class

Comment: Why is it that you have to have the receiver inside of your Activity? There are other design patterns you could follow like passing messages from your receiver to your Activity perhaps via LocalBroadcasts. Just because it works doesn't mean its the right pattern to use.

Comment: I wasn't actually aware of the LocalBroadcasts. I guess I'll try that. It's just that from the samples I've checked online, this was how they would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the first line of the receiver declaration to:
`<receiver android:name="com.example.alarmsound.MainActivity$AlarmReceiver">`. That should let Android detect your class through the manifest.

The `$` symbol is used to reference inner classes in the Android Manifest.

Comment: Yeap, just tried that. It gave me a RuntimeException saying that it was unable to instantiate receiver. At the end of the error, it also says that the AlarmReceiver class has no zero argument constructor.

Comment: Yup, the code worked. Android is able to detect your receiver now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So as you mentioned the the `AlarmReceiver` class cannot be recognized in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. So I tried it out in Android Studio and it seems the format should be something like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity$AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.alarmsound.MainActivity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Tried running the code but it returns an error where the app crashes. Anyways, I think that's a different concern now.

Comment: The package name isn't actually necessary in defining a receiver, normaly ".ClassName" is good enough, as it refers to the global package of the application, more specifically Such as <App Package>.ClassName